# fcntl.ioctl constantly resulting in TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Tags: python, arduino, embedded-linux

I am making a program on an Arduino Portenta x8 running Ubuntu 22.0.4. Part of the program has a thread tight polling a GPIO pin on the board to read a linear actuator's encoder. I've been using python-periphery for this, but I've noticed that upon reading other GPIO pins while having another thread polling the encoder, after a few seconds I get a TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out. If the error doesn't explicitly occur, I've noticed sometimes the pin readings will result in random values instead of the actual signals being input, as if they're in a floating state.

The test code I wrote to test this issue is as follows:

```
from periphery import GPIO
import threading

def poll(gpio, num):
    while True:
        print("GPIO {num}: {gpio}".format(num=num, gpio=gpio.read()))

if __name__ =="__main__":
    gpio0 = GPIO("/dev/gpiochip5", 0, "in")
    gpio1 = GPIO("/dev/gpiochip5", 1, "in")
    # creating thread
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=poll, args=(gpio0,0,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=poll, args=(gpio1,1,))

    # starting thread 1
    t1.start()
    # starting thread 2
    t2.start()

    # wait until thread 1 is completely executed
    t1.join()
    # wait until thread 2 is completely executed
    t2.join()

    # both threads completely executed
    print("Done!")
```

The full error message is as follows:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2 (poll):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/periphery/gpio_cdev1.py", line 323, in read
Exception in thread Thread-1 (poll):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/periphery/gpio_cdev1.py", line 323, in read
    fcntl.ioctl(self._line_fd, Cdev1GPIO._GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, data)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    fcntl.ioctl(self._line_fd, Cdev1GPIO._GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/wall_panels/bb_ws/src/spc_unit_tester/spc_unit_tester/polling_test.py", line 6, in poll
  File "/home/dev/wall_panels/bb_ws/src/spc_unit_tester/spc_unit_tester/polling_test.py", line 6, in poll
    print("GPIO {num}: {gpio}".format(num=num, gpio=gpio.read()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/periphery/gpio_cdev1.py", line 325, in read
    print("GPIO {num}: {gpio}".format(num=num, gpio=gpio.read()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/periphery/gpio_cdev1.py", line 325, in read
    raise GPIOError(e.errno, "Getting line value: " + e.strerror)
periphery.gpio.GPIOError: [Errno 110] Getting line value: Connection timed out
    raise GPIOError(e.errno, "Getting line value: " + e.strerror)
periphery.gpio.GPIOError: [Errno 110] Getting line value: Connection timed out
Done!
```

I tried adding time.sleep() at the bottom of each loop, and tested different sleep values. Having longer delays such as 1 second or 0.5 seconds seems to fix the error, but shorter delays such as 0.02 seconds (20ms) results in the same errors. Since I need the polling to have a short delay to not miss any encoder signals, I'm hoping to find some other way or workaround for polling this encoder signal (actuator for reference: https://www.firgelliauto.com/blogs/tutorials/synchronous-control-of-two-optical-linear-actuators-using-an-arduino).

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks!